How to force unregistration a service with eureka registry server?
I want to disconnect a instance of Spring Boot service with Eureka registry server when this service run into some problem. But I don't know how to do this.
Sometimes, running for my instance, a service running into Gc overhead limit exception, this kind of exception not make my service down immediately, but they can't handle request from web/app client anymore, and Eureka registry server identify that instance of service is UP, then gateway service is keep routing traffic to this, it makes response of my server is success alternating with fail.
I want to do something to handle this type of issue. Something like if this exception occurs, I will disconnect this instance of service with eureka, to the gateway service, not routing traffic to this instance anymore.
How can I do this?
